# How can I use Google Analytics without its gtag.js library

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am having some pages where I need to track page views and get data for reports. So I need to use some tracking events without using gtag.js.

I have tried solutions like [GIF Request Parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview)

But this solution was there in ga.js and its a legacy

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to stack please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this will help you avoid asking off topic questions int he future

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @DaImTo I have updated my question and added what was implemented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format used in your linked documentation is deprecated since Google introduced Universal Analytics in 2012.

However the current solution to send requests to Googke Analytics without a library, the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1), works broadly the same way. You have an endpoint (google-analytics.com/collect) and add the necessary parameters as described in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters), depending on what kind of interaction you want to track.  The endpoint returns a 200 http status and a gif (no matter if the request has actually been logged in analytics, this just confirms that you actually hit the server).